# Регулярное выражение для Notepad++

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Есть много строк и нужно в каждой строке найти первый символ цифру 6, если нашел заменить на другой символ. Помогите
Пример:
123456
998316
000000
678913 (Вот тут первый символ цифра 6 - его и заменяем на 0 и получаем 078913)
И так искать до тех пор пока не пройдется по всем строкам

Comment: Покажите ваше выражение, пример текста и желаемый результат.

Comment: Как насчет более конкретного заголовка для вопроса?

Comment: @Эникейщик обновил свой вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: `Ctrl-H`, Найти: `^(6)`, заменить: `0`, режим regular expression, `заменить всё`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew обновил свой вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan вы просто лучший из лучших!

Comment: Т.е. нужно найти строчки, где первый символ - 6, а не первую 6 в строке?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan `^(6)` группа захвата не обязательна, так же сработает с `^6`

Answer (score 1):

Найти строчки, которые начинаются с 6, можно и без регулярных выражений:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`\r\n` - перевод строки (в Windows).

Первую строчку придется проверить вручную.

Comment: Можно установить точку на `Regular expression` и обозначить начало строки символом `^`, тогда не нужно будет изощраться с \r\n

Comment: @PotroNik можно, да.

Answer (score 0):

Заменить `^6` на `0` с использованием регулярок:

[image: скриншот]

[image: скринвидео]

Comment: А попробуйте своё выражение с `666667`. `^6` не работает в Notepad++ так, как в других средах.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, а может сначала сам проверишь, вместо того, чтоб минусы лепить? Работает.

Comment: ОК, я проверил только удаление. Замена работает.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, да, действительно, с удалением работает немного неожиданно. Получается, у них после исчезновения первого символа сдвигается и начало строки. Не знал про такую особенность, спасибо!